# C# EF 6.0 - Update Navigation Property Collections on objects added to context collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Navigation property collections (possibly all navigation properties) are not updated when adding objects to the context table collections.

E.G.

Class A has a collection of Class B's.
A new B is added to the context.B's collection, where it should be retrievable from the A.B's collection based on the key values provided.  It can be retrieved from the context.B's collection directly, but it ***does not*** get added to the A.B's collection properly when context.SaveChanges() is called (this is the crux of the issue).

What bit of configuration is missing that will trigger the update of the A.B's collection anytime a new object is added do the context.B's collection?  Documentation leads me to believe that it should all 'just work' as soon as SaveChanges() is called, but it most definitely is *not*.

Currently, anytime I add a new object to a context collection, I have to also **manually** add it to the navigation property collections of other entities where it *should be* accessible automatically.  This makes an absolute mess out of what should be simple code, and leads me to believe either I'm doing something wrong with the setup, or there is a major bug in the EF that I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Buried in the comments of another similar question, was the gem I was looking for that forces reloading of navigation property collections.

[Refresh entity framework collection property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709685/refresh-entity-framework-collection-property)

> stackoverflow.com/questions/9081244/… use
>   context.Entry(myPerson).Collection(p => p.Addresses).CurrentValue.Clear();
>     and
>   context.Entry(myPerson).Collection(p => p.Addresses).Load();

The last bit is the important functional piece that I needed:

```
context.Entry(myPerson).Collection(p => p.Addresses).Load();
```